# In excel,how do you generate random times so that they only contain even-numbered hours (e.g., 2:46pm, 4:43pm, 6:32pm, etc.) between 10 am and 8pm?

Tags: excel

In excel,how do you generate random times so that they only contain even-numbered hours (e.g., 2:46pm, 4:43pm, 6:32pm, etc.) between 10 am and 8pm?

Answer (score 5):

For your hours, you need to generate a random number between 5 and 9 then multiply it by 2. The minutes can be completely random and it looks like you don't care about the seconds so i will choose 0.

```
=TIME(RANDBETWEEN(5,9)*2,RANDBETWEEN(0,59),0)
```

If you want to include 8:00 PM, the following should make it equally random:

```
=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,5*60+1)=1,TIME(20,0,0),TIME(RANDBETWEEN(5,9)*2,RANDBETWEEN(0,59),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TIME(INT(RAND()*5)*2+10,INT(RAND()*60),INT(RAND()*60))
```

### UPDATE

Consider include 8:00pm, another way here(using two columns):

```
A: =TIME(0, INT(RAND()*(5*60+1)), 0)  -- from 00:00:00 to  05:00:00 (include 5*60 seconds)
                                    -- RAND() >=0 but < 1 so INT(RAND()*(5*60+1)) has the same effect to RANDBETWEEN(0,5*60)
B: =TIME(10,0,0) + TIME(HOUR(A1)*2,MINUTE(A1), 0)  -- from 10:00:00 to 18:00:00 with even hours 
                                                   -- and 20:00:00 included

-- more concise version by @MarkBalhoff's remiding in the comment
B: =TIME(10 + HOUR(A1)*2, MINUTE(A1), 0)
```

Comment: That almost worked. The only thing is it gave me some times that were between 8pm and 8:59pm. Thanks though

Comment: It's not a good idea to use ROUND here because you get an uneven distribution - e.g. ROUND(RAND()*4,0) will generate a number between 0 and 4 but the end points, 0 and 4, will be less likely than the other numbers. better to use INT(RAND()*5)

Comment: @barryhoudini You are right. I was not aware of that.

Comment: Issues with your two part formula... First, I don't see how you ever plan on getting a time after 4:02 PM. Second, you are giving preference to 12:XX PM and 2:XX PM over 10:XX PM because   anything 11:XX becomes 12:XX and anything 1:XX becomes 2:XX but nothing rounds up to 10:XX.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Thank you for reminding my mistake. Now I updated my answer, and tested carefully.

Comment: Much better!! Distribution is great and value range is spot on!! Curiosity: Is there a reason you wrote out `=TIME(10,0,0)+TIME(HOUR(A1)*2,MINUTE(A1),0)` instead of the more concise `=TIME(10+HOUR(A1)*2,MINUTE(A1),0)` ?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff No particular reason, just what I did so far. My purpose was to find an alternate way from others, not for finding a most concise way. Really appreciate for your help to make the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=TIME(RANDBETWEEN(5,9)*2,RANDBETWEEN(0,60),0)
```